# Data Binding with `List<T>`

Tags: c#, .net, reference-type

I write a small program to record data change,it use a DataGridView,and it's datasource is a List, but I have a question on the DataBingding.

```
DataTable dataTable = GetBalance();
List<StockBalance> balances = ReadDataTable(dataTable);
List<StockBalance> stockBalances = (List<StockBalance>)dataGridView1.DataSource ?? new List<StockBalance>();
stockBalances.AddRange(balances);
dataGridView1.DataSource = stockBalances;
```

The above code can't refresh DataGridView, the data in balances will not show in DataGridView while stockBalances contains all new data, but the under code can archieve：

```
balances.AddRange(stockBalances);
dataGridView1.DataSource = balances;
```

I guess the reason is List and StockBalance is reference type,but I don't konw how to validate it, or it's not that?

Hope someone can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A `DataGridView` - any bound control in fact - needs to receive a notification from the data source when the data changes in order to know that it needs to update.  That requires an object that implements the `IBindingList` interface.  The `List<T>` does not implement that interface and so the grid has no idea when data changes in the list and thus doesn't update.

What you should do is bind your list to a `BindingSource` and then bind that to the grid.  In that case, when you make changes to the list you can then call an appropriate method of the `BindingSource`, e.g. `ResetBindings`, to provide an appropriate notification to the grid.

Note that, when I say "notification", I'm talking about an event.  An `IBindingList` object raises its `ListChanged` event and the control handles that event.

Comment: Isn't just having `BindingList<T>` as data source enough for data being updated in the datagridview?

Comment: @Fabio, yes, a `BindingList<T>` will raise a `ListChanged` event automatically when an item is added or removed. You'd still have to call `ResetItem` when editing an existing item though. That said the `BindingList<T>` documentation does say this: "The BindingList<T> class can be used as a base class to create a two-way data-binding mechanism. [...] However, the typical solutions programmer will use a class that provides data binding functionality, such as BindingSource, instead of directly using BindingList<T>". It's not necessarily wrong to use it directly though.

Comment: If you need that DataGridView updates when you change some property of the item in the list, then when using `BindingList<T>` you need implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `T` class.

Comment: @Fabio, indeed, assuming that that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a **[Binding source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx)**:

```
var source = new BindingSource();
List<StockBalance> balances = ReadDataTable(dataTable);
List<StockBalance> stockBalances = (List<StockBalance>)dataGridView1.DataSource ?? new List<StockBalance>();
stockBalances.AddRange(balances);

 source.DataSource = stockBalances;
 dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns=true;
 dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
```